# Why is 2's complement called this way?

Tags: computer-science, binary

So, I'm preparing for a test and one of the preparation questions is as follows:
[image: The question at hand]

I can tell easily that 'a' and 'e' are just wrong and therefore these answers are irrelevant, but taking a look at the other answers, they are all correct in their claim but I could not find which one is the actual reason for the naming.

'b' is true since negation can be done by a logical not followed with adding the constant 1.
'c' is correct as the negation is based on binary addition for example.
'd' is correct since if X had 1 in its LSB then it will have 0 after doing X+X and if it had a 0 in the LSB then it will still have 0 after doing X+X which means its an even number. 
Pleas correct me if I'm wrong anywhere and please let me know the origin of the name 2's complement.

Comment: I think it is (a).  Because if I were to do this in base 10, I would call it the 10's complements method.  But I must admit I am not certain as to *why* it has the name it has.  Seems like a bit of a funny question to me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The "standard" answer is (a). Two's complement is created to preserve arithmetics in binary, so that you can add positive and negative numbers using the same ALU's. Adding the Two's complement representations of -x and x always gives the first power of 2 greater than the bit-width of the representation, thus truncating to zero.

Comment: I forgot that we start from 2^0 so if I have n bits and 1 in the (n+1)th bit it will actually be 2^n. It makes sense that this is the correct answer, thanks.

Comment: Then 7 is the largest positive number that can be represented at 0111, while -7 in Two's complement is 1001. Add those and you get 10000, which gives 0000 when truncated to 4 bits.